# Possible to download observations from a list in SQL? dbSendQuery?

Tags: sql, r

I am using the followng;

```
res2 <- dbSendQuery(wrds, "select CUSIP, DATE, RET, RETX, VOL
                           from CRSP.DSF
                           WHERE DATE >= '2005-01-01' AND DATE <= '2019-04-01' AND CUSIP IN('09179710', '98252610', '69331C10')")

crsp.dsf2 <- dbFetch(res2, n = -1)
```

Where I can download specific `CUSIP` values. However I have these stored as carácter strings.

```
cusip <- c('09179710', '98252610', '69331C10')
```

How can I download them from the `cusip` carácter strings?

```
res2 <- dbSendQuery(wrds, "select CUSIP, DATE, RET, RETX, VOL
                           from CRSP.DSF
                WHERE DATE >= '2019-03-01' AND DATE <= '2019-04-01' AND CUSIP IN(cusip)")
```

The above does not work.

EDIT:

```
cusip <- c('09179710', '98252610', '69331C10', '69331C10')

cusip
cusip <- paste(cusip, collapse = ", ")
cusip
select_string  <- paste0("select CUSIP, DATE, RET, RETX, VOL
                         from CRSP.DSF
                         WHERE DATE >= '2019-03-01' AND DATE <= '2019-04-01' AND 
                         CUSIP IN(", cusip, ")")
res2 <- dbSendQuery(wrds, select_string)
crsp.dsf2 <- dbFetch(res2, n = -1)
```

I get this error;

```
Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  Failed to prepare query: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "C10"
LINE 4: ...                CUSIP IN(09179710, 98252610, 69331C10, 69331...
```

Can the request only handle numeric values? When I run this;

```
res2 <- dbSendQuery(wrds, "select CUSIP, DATE, RET, RETX, VOL
                           from CRSP.DSF
                           WHERE DATE >= '2005-01-01' AND DATE <= '2019-04-01' AND CUSIP IN('09179710', '98252610', '69331C10', '69331C10')")
```

I get a result and it "ignores" `69331C10`. -  So I get 3 out of the 4 results.

When I run this (removing the problem observation);

```
cusip <- c('09179710', '98252610')

cusip
cusip <- paste(cusip, collapse = ", ")
cusip
select_string  <- paste0("select CUSIP, DATE, RET, RETX, VOL
                         from CRSP.DSF
                         WHERE DATE >= '2019-03-01' AND DATE <= '2019-04-01' AND 
                         CUSIP IN(", cusip, ")")
res2 <- dbSendQuery(wrds, select_string)
```

I get the following error;

```
Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  Failed to prepare query: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 4:                          CUSIP IN (09179710, 98252610)
                                       ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

EDIT 2:

```
res2 <- dbSendQuery(wrds, paste0("select CUSIP, DATE, RET, RETX, VOL 
                                 from CRSP.DSF 
                                 WHERE DATE >= '2019-03-01' AND DATE <= '2019-04-01' 
                                 AND CUSIP IN (',"paste0(cusip, collapse = "', '"), "')"))
```

Comment: What is your backend driver: ROracle, RPostgreSQL, RMySQL, odbc?

Comment: I am using a R package: `library(RPostgres)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider parameterization that avoids any string concatenation of SQL code and R values, avoiding the need of handling quotes for strings. Below is a dynamic solution to build a prepared statement with numbered placeholders:  `$1, $2, $3, ...` before binding values from list of data values.

```
library(RPostgreSQL)

cusip <- c('09179710', '98252610')

# PREPARED SQL STATEMENT (NO DATA)
placeholders <- paste0(paste0("$", seq_along(cusip)), collapse=", ")

sql <- paste0("SELECT CUSIP, DATE, RET, RETX, VOL
               FROM CRSP.DSF
               WHERE DATE >= '2019-03-01' AND DATE <= '2019-04-01' 
                 AND CUSIP IN (", placeholders, ")")

# EXECUTE SQL STATEMENT, BINDING VALUES TO PLACEHOLDERS
res2 <- dbSendQuery(wrds, sql, as.list(cusip))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the elements stored in cusip into your select statement. 
One way could be:

```
# add double-quotes to keep the single quotes
cusip <- c("'09179710'", "'98252610'", "'69331C10'")
# paste all elements from cusip into one text element
cusip <- paste(cusip, collapse = ", ")
cusip
# "'09179710', '98252610', '69331C10'"

# paste this together with your select statement
select_string  <- paste0("select CUSIP, DATE, RET, RETX, VOL
                         from CRSP.DSF
                         WHERE DATE >= '2019-03-01' AND DATE <= '2019-04-01' AND 
                         CUSIP IN(", cusip, ")")
select_string 
# [1] "select CUSIP, DATE, RET, RETX, VOL\nfrom CRSP.DSF\nWHERE DATE >= '2019-03-01' AND DATE <= '2019-04-01' AND \nCUSIP IN('09179710', '98252610', '69331C10')"

# execute your select
res2 <- dbSendQuery(wrds, select_string)
```

Comment: No need to change cusip, you can have the single quotes as part of the `collapse`.   `res2 <- dbSendQuery(wrds, paste0("select CUSIP, DATE, RET, RETX, VOL
                           from CRSP.DSF
                WHERE DATE >= '2019-03-01' AND DATE <= '2019-04-01' AND CUSIP IN (',"paste0(cusip, collapse = "', '"), "')"))`

Comment: Sure you could plug it all together, but i think for explanatory purpose it is a bit more visible if this are separate comands. But thats just my oppinion

Comment: Thanks! I think this almost solves my problem, I run into an error however (I have edited the original post showing them)

Comment: i think the ' are missing in your select string. Either you add double quotes to them or use the paste-method @KerryJackson suggested.

Comment: Yes I think the problem is here; `paste0(cusip, collapse = "', '")` which returns `" 88431510, 43258910, 20030N10, 20030N10, 20030N10"`  but it should return something like; `" '88431510', '43258910', '20030N10', '20030N10', '20030N10' "` (I think).

Comment: try cusip <- c("'09179710'", "'98252610'", "'69331C10'"), or in case cusip is large, cusip <- paste0('"', cusip, '"') before you do paste0(cusip, collapse = "', '")

Comment: Add Kerry Jacksons `res2` in EDIT 2 I get this error: `Error: unexpected symbol in:
"                                 WHERE DATE >= '2019-03-01' AND DATE <= '2019-04-01' 
                                 AND CUSIP IN (',"paste0"` - So I am trying to find where the unexpected symbol is.

Comment: Sorry, misplaced comma.  Try `paste0("select CUSIP, DATE, RET, RETX, VOL from CRSP.DSF WHERE DATE >= '2019-03-01' AND DATE <= '2019-04-01' AND CUSIP IN ('", paste0(cusip, collapse = "', '"), "')")`